# Putting different value inside different variable inside for loop in js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to put different values inside inside different variable where values are produced by outer loop and use that variable like array

```
var code = [];
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   code[i] = mp3;
}
```

How can I access variable like this:- code[1] , code[2];

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through an array in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can push the value of mp3 into the array by using .push() as below. Then you can access it by the index of the array you want.

Note that you need to declare what mp3 is - I didn't know if it related to another variable so I just created a test value for it.

```js
var code = [];
var mp3 = "test";
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     code.push(mp3+i);
  }

console.log(code) // gives ["test0","test1","test2","test3","test4"]
console.log(code[0]) // gives test0
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want

```
var code = [];
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   code[i] = mp+"i";
}
alert(code[0])
code[0] will mp0
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values are stored as per above loop , you can simply call code[0] or code[1] , if you are looking for some other information , please provide more details